# Remove empty page allocation for book document class because I am printing single side

Tags: books, printing, emptypage

```
\documentclass [12pt] {book}

\begin {document}

\title {Title}
\maketitle

\tableofcontents
\listoffigures
\listoftables

\chapter {chapter}
content

\end {document}
```

I wish to remove the empty page after table of contents, table of figures and second page after a odd page number chapter because I am printing single side.

edit: The answer was just add [oneside] to \documentclass. Thank you Johaness

Comment: `\documentclass[12pt,oneside]{book}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer was to add [oneside] to \documentclass. Thank you @Johannes_B.